# R package build failure on Mac OS X

Tags: r, mongodb, build, package, cran

The MongoDB driver package [`rmongodb`](https://github.com/gerald-lindsly/rmongodb) crashes R 2.15.2, as per [this issue](https://github.com/gerald-lindsly/rmongodb/issues/11).

The author has fixed the problem on GitHub but CRAN hasn't updated. The author only has access to a Windows platform and cannot build the package for Mac OS X. When I attempt to install the package from source on Mac OS X I get a build error.

```
2087[SPX/r(ss_mongo_rep *)]$ r CMD INSTALL ~/Downloads/rmongodb-master/rmongodb.tar.gz 
* installing to library ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library’
* installing *source* package ‘rmongodb’ ...
** libs
*** arch - i386
make: *** No rule to make target `._api.o', needed by `rmongodb.so'.  Stop.
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rmongodb’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/rmongodb’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/rmongodb’
```

I'd appreciate pointers on how to get around this issue or, perhaps even better, a link to a 64-bit Mac OS X binary for the package.

Comment: Looks like this was resolved via the [rmongodb issue queue on GitHub](https://github.com/gerald-lindsly/rmongodb/issues/11) and fixed in rmongodb 1.0.3.

Comment: If you add this as an answer I will accept it.